# How to escape the forward slash in a sed command

Tags: sed

I'm writing a shell script with this command:

```
sed -e 's/OLD_ITEM/NEW_ITEM/g'
```

But I actually want to do something that includes a directory:

```
sed -e 's/FOLDER/OLD_ITEM/NEW_ITEM/g'
```

How do ignore the forward slash so that the entire line FOLDER/OLD_ITEM is read properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to  escape the `/` as `\/`.

The escape (`\`) preceding a character tells the shell to interpret that character literally.

So use `FOLDER\/OLD_ITEM`

Answer (score 29):

You don't have to use `/` as delimiter in `sed` regexps. You can use whatever character you like, as long as it doesn't appear in the regexp itself:

```
sed -e 's@FOLDER/OLD_ITEM@NEW_ITEM@g'
```

or

```
sed -e 's|FOLDER/OLD_ITEM|NEW_ITEM|g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape it !

```
sed -e 's/FOLDER\/OLD_ITEM/NEW_ITEM/g'
```